# Unable to update yum packages using CentOS 7.5

Tags: centos, yum, centos-7

I have been getting the following error while updating yum packages.

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml
file Trying other mirror.
```

And:

```
[root@system ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
CentOS-7-x86_64-extras                                                                                                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB  00:00:00
CentOS-7-x86_64-os                                                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
CentOS-QPK-7-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Delivery-Sysadm-CentOS-7-noarch                                                                                                                                                                                       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Delivery-Sysadm-CentOS-7-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Delivery-Sysadm-CentOS-nover-noarch                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Delivery-Sysadm-CentOS-nover-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.4 kB  00:00:00
Delivery-Sysadm-nodist-nover-noarch                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Delivery-Sysadm-nodist-nover-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Private-v2cloud-CentOS-7-noarch                                                                                                                                                                                          | 2.4 kB  00:00:00
Private-v2cloud-CentOS-7-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                          | 2.4 kB  00:00:00
Private-v2cloud-CentOS-nover-noarch                                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Private-v2cloud-CentOS-nover-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.4 kB  00:00:00
Private-v2cloud-nodist-nover-noarch                                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
Private-v2cloud-nodist-nover-x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                      | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |  12 kB  00:00:00
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml file
Trying other mirror.

One of the configured repositories failed (CentOS-7 - Base),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
   upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
   distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
   packages for the previous distribution release still work).

3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled

       yum --disablerepo=base ...

4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
   will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
   again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

       yum-config-manager --disable base
   or
       subscription-manager repos --disable=base

5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
   Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
   so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
   slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
   compromise:

       yum-config-manager --save --setopt=base.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1]
Error importing repomd.xml for base: Damaged repomd.xml file
```

When I **curl** the mirror URL, I get the following response:

```
[root@system ~]# curl http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
.
.
.
```

Since curl is getting response, I think there is no network issues and I do not use any proxy in `yum.conf` .

Any lead to fix this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you moved your question I couldn't read your reply. I saw you said you tried `yum clean all` but nothing after that. I'm just testing on a Centos 7 VM

Comment: @user3788685 I tried `yum clean all` but had no luck.

Comment: Another quick idea if you can... run `yum check` then `yum clean packages`, reboot the server if you can, then check again. I'm not certain if a reboot is needed or not but if you can, you might as well to be extra thorough. I doubt it's DNS related too but just in case, be sure to triple check the DNS settings on the server and confirm it's pointed to a correct and working DNS server as you'd expect. Quick ideas that you could try to at least eliminate I suppose if nothing else.